# Execute Store Procedure from Linq to Sql WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure for getting user details. In that there is one input parameter i.e. **@UserName**. Here is my stored procedure

```
USE [Test]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GetUserByUserName]    Script Date: 6/12/2013 6:59:49 PM  ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetUserByUserName]
(
    @UserName VARCHAR(100)
)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

BEGIN TRY
    SELECT      UserID,                 
                FirstName,
                LastName,
                UserName,
                Password,
                PasswordUpdateDate,
                MembershipType,
                IsActive
    FROM        Users
    WHERE       UserName = @UserName
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    EXEC ThrowError
END CATCH
END
```

I want to execute this procedure using Linq to Sql in WCF. I want to return result in **DataTable Object**.

Comment: If you want a DataTable, then the ADO.NET objects would be a better choice than Linq to SQL. ([example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z.aspx))

Comment: If I don't use DataTable, then how can I execute this stored procedure using Linq to Sql ?

Comment: [Here's an example](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx) of using Linq to SQL with stored procedures. Using this method, you'll get back objects instead of a DataTable.